# A Black setup against White's Hippo Attack

Tags: opening

If I'm playing as White against the Hippo Defense, I usually go with this setup.

```
[FEN ""]

1. d4 b6 2. c4 Bb7 3. Nc3 g6 4. e4 Bg7 5. Nf3 e6 6. Be2 d6 7. O-O Ne7 8. Be3 Nd7 9. Qc2 O-O 10. Rad1 h6 11. d5 e5
```

But I don't know what kind of setup I should have if I'm playing as Black against the Hippo. I found that this formation cannot be achieved. Any suggestions? Note that I start with 1...Nf6 against the Catalan opening because I play Nimzo-Indian/Ragozin against 1.d4.

Comment: It is not obvious to me why you could not achieve the same set-up a tempo down. Nothing is dropped on the way if you go, e.g. 1.b3 d5 2.Bb2 c5 3.g3 Nc6 4.Bg2 e5 5.e3 Be6 6.Ne2 Be7 7.0-0 (7.f4!? can be met with 7...f6 or 7...Bf6) Nf6 8.d3 0-0 9.h3 Qc7 10.Nd2 Rad8 (or 10...d4)

Comment: @Evargalo good move order from you. But for me I always start with Nf6 if White starts with g3 (against Catalan or English opening). So a move order that's tough might be: 1. g3 Nf6 2. Bg2 d5 3. b3 c5 4. Bb2 Nc6 5. f4, I can't play f6 or Bf6 because I already committed Nf6. And now I can't play e5!

Comment: how does black play against a hippo?

Comment: @edwinaoliver that was my original question. But I prefer something close to the White setup (with colors reversed) that I mentioned in the original answer. Evargalo gave a good suggestion but I still have some questions about the move order.

Answer (score 2):

The best choice is to aim for quick development. Once White has played 8 moves, you would have pushed the d/e/f- pawns forward, developed three pieces, and castled. White is still in the center. Now aim to absolutely wreck White's position with ...f4

Comment: can you put a fen diagram as an example please? I just got your idea, but I would also want to get the move order correct.

Comment: The move order doesn't matter here. The basic setup is with the d,e,f-pawns developed, Bd6, Nf6, Nc6, 0-0. These moves can be played in any order.

Comment: what about Evargalo's suggestion in the comments up?

Comment: If @Guess601 needs to face 1.g3 with 1...Nf6 (this is said in a comment but should me move to the question itself for clarity), then he has to forget about all plans with ...f5. This suggestion cannot solve his problem.

Comment: @Evargalo yea you're right, I forgot about that! Any suggestions?

Comment: Otherwise, if you can't play f4-f5, you can perhaps go for a pawn storm on the side the opponent has castled. However, it would be difficult to break through Black's position.

Answer (score 1):

One option would just be to copy their hippo and just copy the setup.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer, i.e., state the strategies which Black shall implement?

Comment: go b6, g6, d6 e6 Bg7 Bb7, just do basically the exact same thing as white's doing, the exact move order isn't super important due to the fact there isn't any immediate conflict between the two sides.